# Python Module or Algorithm to produce same results as Mathematica LinearModelFit

Tags: python, python-2.7, wolfram-mathematica

First I don't really know Mathematica and I haven't done stats in a very long time.

I have been trying to find (Google and RTFM) a way to reproduce the results produced by the Mathematica `LinearModelFit` function using `scipy.stats.linregress`. It is now obvious that this is not the way to go except for the most simple cases.

`LinearModelFit[ydata, 1/(2 n - x)^100, x]`

produces `16.3766 + <<70>>/(2580 - x)^100`

If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

data: http://pastebin.com/RTp5em0W

Screen shot of Mathematica Notebook: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT43O.jpg

Note: I did not do the Mathematica work. ddd is the data that can be found at the pastebin link. The y in the denominator should be x.

Comment: you might want to post actual working mathematica code ( underscores are not allowed in symbol names ) and some sample data.

Comment: I have done as requested.

Comment: I am not familiar with mathematica but I suggest you to look at `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`.  There is a linear regression functionality also in `statsmodels`. I hope this can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the python solution, but one way to handle this problem is to transform your x data according to the functional form you are supplying as the argument to `LinearModelFit` :

```
 n=1290
 LinearModelFit[ydata, 1/(2 n - x)^100, x]["BestFit"]
```

> 16.1504 + 1.471945513739138*10^315/(2580 - x)^100

is equivalent to:

```
 xtransform = 1/(2 n - #)^100  & /@ Range[Length[ydata]];
 LinearModelFit[Transpose[{xtransform, ydata}], x, x]["BestFit"]
```

> 16.1504 + 1.471945513739138*10^315 x

You should readily be able to do that transform and use standard linear regression in python. You might have precision issues due to the large exponent however.

Answer (score 0):

A simple algorithm requiring no complex functionality can be made for coding in any language.

The `y` data is imported.

```
y = {11.56999969, 14.47999954, ... , 340.730011, 202.1699982, 4054.949951};
```

Linear regression coefficients `a` and `b` are found by solving the normal equations.  (See note below for derivation).  Once computed they can be reused without needing a solver.

```
Clear[a, b, n, Σx, Σy, Σxy, Σx2]

Column[{a, b} = Simplify[First[{a, b} /. Solve[{
    (* Normal equations for straight line *)
    Σy == n a + b Σx,
    Σxy == a Σx + b Σx2},
   {a, b}]]]]
```

> (Σx Σxy - Σx2 Σy)/(Σx^2 - n Σx2)
>
> (-n Σxy + Σx Σy)/(Σx^2 - n Σx2)

`X` is linearised to `x` according to the model.

```
n = Length[y]
```

> 1267

```
X = Range[n];
x = Map[1/(2 n - #)^100 &, X];
```

Quantities are computed:

```
Σx = Sum[x[[i]], {i, n}];
Σy = Sum[y[[i]], {i, n}];
Σxy = Sum[x[[i]]*y[[i]], {i, n}];
Σx2 = Sum[x[[i]]^2, {i, n}];
```

Implementing the coefficient formulae:

```
a = (Σx Σxy - Σx2 Σy)/(Σx^2 - n Σx2)
b = (Σx Σy - n Σxy)/(Σx^2 - n Σx2)
```

> 16.65767846718208
>
> 4.213538401691473*10^313

Plotting the regression line on the linearised data (with scaling).

```
scaled = 10^340;

Show[ListPlot[Transpose[{x scaled, y}],
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 30}}],
 ListPlot[Transpose[{x scaled, Table[a + b i, {i, x}]}],
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Reapplying the model, the least-squares fit is: `a + b/(2 n - X)^100`

```
Show[ListPlot[Transpose[{X, y}],
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 400}}],
 Plot[a + b/(2 n - X)^100, {X, 0, n},
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 400}}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

This matches the built-in solution from Mathematica shown below.

Also calculating R squared.

```
(* Least-squares regression of y on x *) 
Array[(Y[#] = a + b x[[#]]) &, n]; 
Array[(e[#] = y[[#]] - Y[#]) &, n];
(* Residual or unexplained sum of squares *)
RSS = Sum[e[i]^2, {i, n}];
(* Total sum of squares in the dependent variable, measured about its mean *)
TSS = (y - Mean[y]).(y - Mean[y]);
(* Coefficient of determination, R^2 *)
R2 = 1 - RSS/TSS
```

> 0.230676

Checking with Mathematica's built-in functionality.

```
Clear[x]

lm = LinearModelFit[y, 1/(2 n - x)^100, x];
lm["BestFit"]
```

[image]

```
lm["RSquared"]
```

> 0.230676

**Note on the normal equations**

Source: [Econometric Methods](https://books.google.com/books/about/Econometric_Methods.html?id=vhKqQgAACAAJ)

[image]